# How to setup new reactjs project on local environment or system?

Tags: reactjs

I started to learn reactjs for front end in web development. For learning purpose I  install node and npm on my local system below are the versions of node and npm

**node v8.11.3**

**npm  v5.6.0**

and I have run bellow command

**npm init**

and create pakage.json following file using command

```
{
  "name": "loginpage",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.9.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "rizwan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

in next step i run following command install node and react dependencies
**npm install**
and then I run **create-react-app hello-world** commands but I did't find any change in my current local project folder exception pakage.json file I don't know that where I am doing mistake. Guide in right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Create-react-app creates everything from scratch, you don't need to create a folder or `npm init`, anything like that.

Just run `create-react-app my-project` and you'll have everything you need in the `my-project` folder.

Answer (score 0):

To create react app 
first, install create-react-app globally
then, run these commands

`create-react-app app-name
cd app-name
npm run start`

I prefer to use Yarn instead of npm